# Grunt JSDoc: Use jsdoc JSON file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jsdoc

I want to set up a Grunt task to run JSDoc. I am using [grunt-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-jsdoc) which the JSDoc npm page recommends. It works ok, but I cannot use my jsdoc.json file I have created.

```
{
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
  },
  "source": {
    "include": [
      "lib/",
      "routes/",
      "README.md"
    ]
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false
  },
  "opts": {
    "destination": "public/docs"
  }
}
```

I have found that when I pull bits out of the JSDoc and put them in Grunt, I have no issues:

```
//This will generate a blank public/docs folder
jsdoc: {
    dist : {
        src: './jsdoc.json'
        options: {
            destination: 'public/docs'
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to just reference the JSON file, and have it work. Currently, doing this will not generate errors, but it doesn't do anything other then creating an empty doc folder in the base directory.

```
jsdoc: {
    dist : {
        src: './jsdoc.json'
    }
}
```

I have also verified that the jsdoc.json file is correct `jsdoc -c jsdoc.json`

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the conf file into the options property.

```
jsdoc: {
   dist: {
     options: {
          configure: './jsdoc.json'
       }
   }
}
```